# How can I align my title to be flush with margin and format contents?

Tags: titlesec

I've had to alter my contents page to fit in with requirements for my thesis.

I need my chapter headings to read X.0 "chapter name". e.g. 1.0 Introduction

I've managed to do this using the title sec package, however it has caused a couple of new formatting issues that I can't fix. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\linespread{1.3}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}.0}
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand*{\chaptername}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
 {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{section1}

\end{document}
```

My questions:

1. The title now sits slightly indented on the page e.g.

   1.0 Introduction

Is there a way to make it flush with the margin?

1. My contents now reads: 1.0Introduction etc.

Is there a way to create space between the number and the title?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you really need to use `titlesec` to format it or can you use only `report` class and just change the chapter format?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: It's not really clear what you want in the table of contents. What about a reference to a chapter? I guess you'd want “As we shall see in Chapter 3”, not “in Chapter 3.0”.

Comment: At present my table of contents looks like this:
1.0Introcution
  1.1  Section 1
  1.2  Section 2

I need a way of creating a space between the 1.0 and the word introduction.

Comment: What about relative indentation?

Comment: Problem resolved by KarkKoeller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\linespread{1.3}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}.0}
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
 {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{section1}

\end{document}
```

---

### EDIT

To fix the ToC issue, you can load the package `tocloft` and put the following lines in the preamble:

```
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{2.5em}
\setlength{\cftsecindent}{2.5em}
\setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{4.8em}
```

The first one gives more room for chapter numbers, the other ones are to reposition sections and subsections.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\linespread{1.3}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}.0}
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
 {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}

\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{2.5em}
\setlength{\cftsecindent}{2.5em}
\setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{4.8em}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{section1}
\subsection{subsection1}


\end{document}
```

Output (ToC):

[image]

Comment: Thanks this fixes the title issue, however the contents is still missing a space between the 1.0 and the Introduction. eg. 1.0Introduction instead of 1.0 Introduction

Comment: @Suzanne Sorry, I didn't see that issue. It is now fixed in the edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}% delete for sans serif titles
\linespread{1.3}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{section1}
foo

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The OP wants `1.0 Introduction` as title.

Comment: I know, but that is not the problem for the alignment. Copy the two lines and everything is fine. I do not like such a counting of a chapter!